# About TLB & data Caches

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, paging, tlb

I know how cpu access the data with the help of TLB & cache.
But i have confusion , whether both data cache & TLB shares the same CPU cache or MMU hardware is having seperate cache for TLB. Who will flush the contents of TLB and data caches when context switch happens ?

Comment: The TLB cache is usually separate, also different caches for instructions and data.  Invalidating the cache is an operating system duty.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on the CPU.

Since you're talking about "MMU hardware", I assume that you have a very old book. The MMU has been very tightly integrated into most CPUs for at least the past 20 years.

Anyway, let's start with the caches. On most CPUs you'll encounter every day, like i386 and x86_64, the caches are physically indexed. This means that they cache things on the physical memory access and as such there is no need to flush them on context switch.

On other CPU architectures with virtual caches, there are multiple mechanisms to ensure cache coherency. On some with fully virtually address cache, it's the job of the operating system to flush the whole cache on context switch. On some, the virtually indexed cache also has a physical tag to make sure that whatever we got from the cache is right (the cache line lookup is done in parallel with the TLB lookup, so checking the physical address isn't a problem). On others there's an explicit context number that the operating system allocates for every different context that is also part of the cache lookup and there's no need to flush caches on context switch.

For the TLB there are basically three main flavors. One is the one with the explicit context number just like for the cache, so you don't need to do anything on a context switch. The second flavor automatically flushes the TLB when the new page tables are loaded (this is i386 and x86_64). Some older CPUs required an explicit TLB flush after loading the new page tables. The third way to do TLBs is to fill them entirely in software in special trap handlers.

For the question if TLB and normal caches share memory or not. Usually no. It would be hard to get a good balance between how much TLB vs. cache you need. Also, looking things up in the TLB and the cache is done quite differently and there are different needs for keeping things coherent. That being said, classically the TLB was always loaded from the physical memory and some CPUs even required cache flushing before the TLB could be loaded. In Core 2 Intel started loading the TLB from the CPU caches which led to a hilarious amount of bugs in early Core 2 CPUs and even some rewriting of low level memory management documentation which basically made all future Intel CPUs not backwards compatible and there are many old operating system kernels that won't run correctly on Core 2 and newer Intel CPUs.